# Como pegar somente números entre parenteses em Python com expressão regular

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

```
Texto = "54 oz (163 g)"
```

Quero que o resultado seja apenas 163

Answer (score 3):

Você pode fazer assim:

```
\((\d+) g\)
```

A primeira e ultima contra-barra é para escapar o parenteses, `(\d+)` irá capturar somente os dígitos dentro do parenteses. O código completo:

```
import re
Texto = "54 oz (163 g)"
Resultado = re.search('\((\d+) g\)', Texto)
print(Resultado[1])
```

> Podes ver funcionando em [repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/stack-289820)

Comment: Se não quiser trabalhar com grupos, uma adaptação desta expressão seria esta: `(?!\()\d+(?=\s*[a-zA-Z]\))`, em que a [demo pode ser vista neste link](https://regex101.com/r/QV3qRx/1)

Comment: @danieltakeshi seria interessante você colocar ela como resposta!

Answer (score 2):

Um complemento a resposta do @wmsouza.

Se a unidade de medida for escalar (mg, g, kg, e assim por diante), a expressão regular poderá ser alterada **'((\d+) \w+)'** como apresentado no trecho abaixo:

```
Resultado = re.search('\((\d+) \w+\)', Texto)
print(Resultado.group(1))
```

Comment: Só um adendo, eu também me confundo com o `\w`, mas o \w é equivalente ao: `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`. Então iria capturar números também. Mas esta expressão daria certo no exemplo dado pelo OP.

Comment: @danieltakeshi funcionaria sim, perfeitamente. 
No entanto, em minha analise pessoal, para leitura e manutenção de código, o simples é melhor. ;D